# Instant File Initialization on Shared drive

Tags: sql-server, performance, restore

I asked something similar to this before, but previously I had asked about moving backups to a shared location. This time I am curious: if I want to restore a database on a shared drive, do I need to enable IFI on that server or just the server that is running SQL Server?

The reason I ask is I am restoring a pretty large database and its been stuck at 100% restored for the last couple hours. The wait type in `sp_whoisactive` is:

```
(28472716ms) `PREEMPTIVE_OS_WRITEFILEGATHER.
```

The only time I've seen that is when IFI is not on, but I *do* have it enabled on the SQL Server, but it is not enabled on the shared drive server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*<sub>Community Wiki answer generated from comments on the question, from [Bob Klimes](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/14734/bob-klimes), [Sean Gallardy](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/41723/sean-gallardy), and [Aaron Bertrand](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/1186/aaron-bertrand).</sub>*

---

You'll need to enable [Instant File Initialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/database-instant-file-initialization?view=sql-server-ver16) (IFI) on the server holding the disk. Restart SQL Server for it to take effect.

You can test if IFI is working on the share by creating a database on the share with [trace flags 3004 and 3605](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sql_pfe_blog/how-and-why-to-enable-instant-file-initialization) turned on. Output is written to the SQL Server error log.

> *If IFI is working, there will not be any entries for zeroing the mdf file.*

IFI does appear to work with network shares, but for me the creation of a test database took 45 seconds on the share and less than 1 second locally. Even with IFI enabled, you might still have performance problems.